# Notation for Lp spaces

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

I do not have a lot of experience in analysis, but I do know the definition of the space $L^p(X)$ to be the complex valued measurable functions with
\begin{equation}
\int|f|^pd\mu < \infty
\end{equation}
I was reading a couple of articles, and was wondering about what $L^p(\Omega; \mathbb{R})$ means with the semicolon in the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemytskii_operator (under "Boundedness Theorem").

Comment: I don't think that $L^p(X)$ consisting of complex valued functions is standard. Generally, whether we are working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ should be specified by the author. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's the subset of $L^p(\Omega)$ containing maps whose range is strictly real (i.e., imaginary part 0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also reading more texts which have the notation $L^p(D; \mathbb{R}^k)$. I thought L^p spaces consisted of real-valued functions. What does it mean in this case. Is it the set of functions $f$ with $\int_D \Vert f \Vert_{\mathbb{R}^k} < \infty$?